# Bot gets data of sitemap, parses it and send message to Telegram channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, telegram

## UPDATED - 25-12-2021

> Summary:
>
> - Renamed **start.py** --> **bot.py**
> - Modified a lot of code in **bot.py**
> - Modified code in **sitemap.py**
> - Created **init.py**
>   Check the update code in the bottom of this question.

I have just started to learn Python and have developed a small bot for Telegram.

This goal is to download a `sitemap.xml` file ([*sample*](https://echemosunbitstazo.es/sitemap.xml)) and compare it for changes with `urls_old.txt` then send the results in a message to the Telegram channel.

### OLD CODE

#### `start.py`

```
import requests, time, sitemap, textwrap

class Telegram:

  def __init__(self):
    self.api = "https://api.telegram.org/bot"
    self.token = "XX"
    self.connection = self.api + self.token

  def get_sitemap(self):
    self.sitemap = sitemap.Sitemap()
    self.sitemap.get_sitemap()
    self.sitemap.parse_sitemap_data()
    self.sitemap.create_file()
    self.sitemap.read_file()
    self.sitemap.update_file()
    self.sitemap.pages_deleted = self.sitemap.get_pages_deleted()
    self.sitemap.pages_created = self.sitemap.get_pages_created()
    if self.sitemap.pages_created == None and self.sitemap.pages_deleted == None:
      self.sm_changes = None
      pass
    elif not self.sitemap.pages_created and not self.sitemap.pages_deleted:
      self.sm_changes = None
      pass
    elif None == self.sitemap.pages_created or not self.sitemap.pages_created:
      self.sitemap.pages_deleted = "\n".join(self.sitemap.pages_deleted)
      self.sm_changes = textwrap.dedent("""
         Hi folks!

        Pages have been deleted:
        ♻️  - %s
        """ % (self.sitemap.pages_deleted))
    elif None == self.sitemap.pages_deleted or not self.sitemap.pages_deleted:
      self.sitemap.pages_created = "\n".join(self.sitemap.pages_created)
      self.sm_changes = textwrap.dedent("""
         Hi folks!

        Pages have been created:
        - %s
        """ % (self.sitemap.pages_created))
    elif None != self.sitemap.pages_created and None != self.sitemap.pages_deleted and len(self.sitemap.pages_created) != 0 and len(self.sitemap.pages_deleted) != 0:
      self.sitemap.pages_deleted = "\n".join(self.sitemap.pages_deleted)
      self.sitemap.pages_created = "\n".join(self.sitemap.pages_created)
      self.sm_changes = textwrap.dedent("""
         Hi folks!

        Pages have been created:
         - %s
        Pages have veen deleted:
        ♻️  - %s
        """ % (self.sitemap.pages_created, self.sitemap.pages_deleted))
    else:
      self.sm_changes = None
      pass

  def send_message(self,chat_id):
    self.instance=self.get_sitemap()
    self.message = self.sm_changes
    if None == self.message:
      pass
    else:
      self.url = self.connection + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + chat_id + '&text={}'.format(self.message)
      requests.get(self.url)

o = Telegram()

while True:
  time.sleep(30)
  o.send_message("XXX")
```

This is the Sitemap:

```
import requests, shutil
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Sitemap:

  def __init__(self):
    self.sitemap_url = "https://echemosunbitstazo.es/sitemap.xml"
#    self.sitemap_url = "file:///home/sincorchetes/Projects/echemosunbitstazo-docs/sitemap.xml"
    self.url_old_fn = "urls_old.txt"
    self.url_new_fn = "urls_news.txt"
    self.new_pages = []
    self.old_pages = []
  def get_sitemap(self):
    try:
      self.sitemap_data = requests.get(self.sitemap_url)
      return self.sitemap_data
    except:
      print("Something was wrong")

  def parse_sitemap_data(self):
    self.sitemap_parse_data = BeautifulSoup(self.sitemap_data.text, 'html.parser')
    self.urls = self.sitemap_parse_data.find_all('loc')
    for url in self.urls:
      self.new_pages.append(url.get_text())

  def printp(self):
    print(self.pages_deleted)

  def create_file(self):
    with open(self.url_new_fn,"w") as f:
      for url in self.new_pages:
        f.write(url + "\n")
      f.close()

  def read_file(self):
    with open(self.url_old_fn) as f:
      for url in f.read().splitlines():
        self.old_pages.append(url)
      f.close()

  def update_file(self):
    try:
      shutil.copyfile(self.url_new_fn,self.url_old_fn)
    except:
      print("Something was wrong updating the file.")

  def get_pages_created(self):
    self.pages_created = [i for i in self.new_pages + self.old_pages if i not in self.old_pages]
    return self.pages_created

  def get_pages_deleted(self):
    self.pages_deleted = [i for i in self.new_pages + self.old_pages if i not in self.new_pages]
    return self.pages_deleted

if __name__ == "__main__":
  pass
```

### MODIFIED CODE

#### **sitemap.py**

```
from requests import get as GetSitemap
from textwrap import dedent as FormatMessage
from shutil import copyfile
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Sitemap:

  def __init__(self):
    self.sitemap_url = "https://echemosunbitstazo.es/sitemap.xml"
    self.url_old_fn = "urls_old.txt"
    self.url_new_fn = "urls_news.txt"
    self.new_pages = []
    self.old_pages = []
    self.get_sitemap()
    self.parse_sitemap_data()
    self.create_file()
    self.read_file()
    self.update_file()
    self.pages_deleted = self.get_pages_deleted()
    self.pages_created = self.get_pages_created()

    if self.pages_created == None and self.pages_deleted == None:
      self.sm_changes = None
      pass
    elif not self.pages_created and not self.pages_deleted:
      self.sm_changes = None
      pass
    elif None == self.pages_created or not self.pages_created:
      self.pages_deleted = "\n".join(self.pages_deleted)
      self.sm_changes = FormatMessage("""
         Hi folks!

        Pages have been deleted:
        ♻️  - %s
        """ % (self.pages_deleted))
    elif None == self.pages_deleted or not self.pages_deleted:
      self.pages_created = "\n".join(self.pages_created)
      self.sm_changes = FormatMessage("""
         Hi folks!

        Pages have been created:
        - %s
        """ % (self.pages_created))
    elif None != self.pages_created and None != self.pages_deleted and len(self.pages_created) != 0 and len(self.pages_deleted) != 0:
      self.pages_deleted = "\n".join(self.pages_deleted)
      self.pages_created = "\n".join(self.pages_created)
      self.sm_changes = FormatMessage("""
         Hi folks!

        Pages have been created:
         - %s
        Pages have veen deleted:
        ♻️  - %s
        """ % (self.pages_created, self.pages_deleted))
    else:
      self.sm_changes = None
      pass

  def get_sitemap(self):
    try:
      self.sitemap_data = GetSitemap(self.sitemap_url)
      return self.sitemap_data
    except:
      print("Something was wrong")

  def parse_sitemap_data(self):
    self.sitemap_parse_data = BeautifulSoup(self.sitemap_data.text, 'html.parser')
    self.urls = self.sitemap_parse_data.find_all('loc')
    for url in self.urls:
      self.new_pages.append(url.get_text())

  def printp(self):
    print(self.pages_deleted)

  def create_file(self):
    with open(self.url_new_fn,"w") as f:
      for url in self.new_pages:
        f.write(url + "\n")
      f.close()

  def read_file(self):
    with open(self.url_old_fn) as f:
      for url in f.read().splitlines():
        self.old_pages.append(url)
      f.close()

  def update_file(self):
    try:
      copyfile(self.url_new_fn,self.url_old_fn)
    except:
      print("Something was wrong updating the file.")

  def get_pages_created(self):
    self.pages_created = [i for i in self.new_pages + self.old_pages if i not in self.old_pages]
    return self.pages_created

  def get_pages_deleted(self):
    self.pages_deleted = [i for i in self.new_pages + self.old_pages if i not in self.new_pages]
    return self.pages_deleted

if __name__ == "__main__":
  pass
```

#### **bot.py**

```
from sitemap import Sitemap
from requests import get as PostMessage

class Tbot:

  def __init__(self):
    self.api = "https://api.telegram.org/bot"
    self.token = "XX:XX"
    self.connection = self.api + self.token

  def get_sitemap(self):
    self.sitemap = Sitemap()
    return self.sitemap

  def send_message(self,chat_id):
    self.instance=self.get_sitemap()
    self.message = self.sitemap.sm_changes
    if None == self.message:
      pass
    else:
      self.url = self.connection + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + chat_id + '&text={}'.format(self.message)
      PostMessage(self.url)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  pass
```

#### **init.py**

```
import bot
from time import sleep

tbot = bot.Tbot()
while True:
  tbot.send_message("-N")
  sleep(30)
```

Looks better?

Comment: What is the contents of `urls_old.txt` and what is a sample message your bot might send, just to get an idea of input & output

Comment: Hi Greddo! The content of urls_old.txt is a sitemap old copy. The first time, I don't have a urls_old.txt so It's created with sitemap.xml info. When it's trying to compare once time, sitemap.xml does not have changes, so, urls_old.txt does not have changes too. If I create a new entry or delete an entry in sitemap.xml. when the send_message method is run, detect the changes and send the data changed. After, urls_old.txt will be replaced by new sitemap.info

Comment: Off-topic, but `25-12-2021` is backwards and hurts my soul.

Comment: What's the mean @Reinderien?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: I don't understand..